# How to fix SDL_CreateWindow error "Window is too large"

Tags: sdl

I'm currently creating a window class for my game engine. When I call SDL_CreateWindow it returns the error "Window is too large". How do I fix this problem? In order to display a window for my game engine.

I've tried setting the window creation flag to SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI and the error is still reported back. I have also set the DPI Awareness in the manifest tool to High DPI Aware. I'm still not able to fix the issue. A code snippet of the Initialise Window function is included below.

```
SDL_DisplayMode displayMode;
for (int32_t i = 0; i < SDL_GetNumVideoDisplays(); i++)
{
    int32_t displayModeCount = SDL_GetCurrentDisplayMode(i, &displayMode);
    if (displayModeCount != 0)
    {
        std::printf("Could not get display mode for video display %d: %s", i, SDL_GetError());
    }
    else
    {
        m_width = displayMode.w;
        m_height = displayMode.h;
        std::printf("Display %d current display mode is %dx%dpx", i, displayMode.w, displayMode.h);

        float DPI;
        SDL_GetDisplayDPI(displayModeCount, nullptr, &DPI, nullptr);
        x = static_cast<int32_t>(m_width * DPI / DPI);
        y = static_cast<int32_t>(m_height * DPI / DPI);
    }
}

uint32_t windowFlags = SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI;
m_pWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(m_title.c_str(), x, y, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, windowFlags);
if (m_pWindow == nullptr)
{
    std::printf("Could not create window: %s", SDL_GetError());
}
```

Even with the  SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI flag set it still prints out the error message and does not display the window. Any help regarding this issue is much appreciated.

Comment: `SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED` is a very high number never intended to be used as width or height. You can pass it instead of `x` or `y` though (which are position of window, not width/height).

Comment: Passing x and y fixed the error and the window is now displayed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue by passing the x and y values to the to SDL_CreateWindow function instead off SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED. Solved by keltar, see comment.